# UITableView doesn't load all objects in NSMutableArray

Tags: xcode, uitableview, nsmutablearray, singleton

I have a UITableView that I'm populating with objects from an NSMutable array. For some reason, the table view always loads the array - 1 object. If the [array count] == 3 it only loads 2 objects (cells)

Here's my code. Can anyone tell me why the tableview always skips either the first or last object in the array? (I can't tell which)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // singleton class containing NSMutable array
    sharedEventData = [EventData sharedDataInstance]; 

    self.navigationController.delegate = self;

    // if this returns 10 the tableview always loads 9 objects. count -1
    NSLog(@"eventList count: %u", [sharedEventData.listOfEvents count]);

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    // sharedEventData.listOfEvents is my NSMutableArray
    return [sharedEventData.listOfEvents count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    EKEvent *currentEvent = [sharedEventData.listOfEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSDate *date = [currentEvent startDate];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];

    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    // Get the event at the row selected and display it's title
    cell.textLabel.text = [[sharedEventData.listOfEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] title];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = dateString;

    //NSLog(@"date string: %@", dateString);


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Under your current NSLog statement, add NSLog(@"%@", sharedEventData.listOfEvents); What do you get in the output when you run this?

Answer (score 0):

first you give some static data in array in didload method then check if it return correct answer then check in numberOfRowsInSection what is the return value . i think this is work and you find out your problem and one thing in didload you remove reloadtable method because didload call 1st time and then table also reload

Comment: because numberOfRowsInSection return number of rows and i think this is return wrong number and you confused on it